# How to clear those warning on Xcode8?

Tags: swift3, ios10, xcode8

Recently, I am bring up my project to Swift3.0. And fix the upgrade issues on Xcode8.0. Some strange warning messages show up which not happen in Xcode7.

```
Painter Z index: 1023 is too large (max 255)
Painter Z index: 1023 is too large (max 255)
Painter Z index: 1023 is too large (max 255)
Painter Z index: 1023 is too large (max 255)
Painter Z index: 1023 is too large (max 255)
Painter Z index: 1023 is too large (max 255)
ERROR /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/VectorKit_Sim/VectorKit-1228.30.7.17.9/GeoGL/GeoGL/GLCoreContext.cpp 1763: InfoLog SolidRibbonShader:
ERROR /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/VectorKit_Sim/VectorKit-1228.30.7.17.9/GeoGL/GeoGL/GLCoreContext.cpp 1764: WARNING: Output of vertex shader 'v_gradient' not read by fragment shader
```

Any Expert know how to fix it? Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Hi noel, posting a code, that is related to these messages, at leanst the code causing warnings, would be pretty helpful.

Comment: I am not sure which part is related. I just add one MapView on my UIViewController, then add some annotations on it.

Comment: You only placed a result, not the code which is supposed to be a source of the problem. [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Its very difficult to locate the trigger codes. That's why I didn't upload any codes.

Comment: I saw this v_gradient error. Only occurs for me on a push to a Viewcontroller that has an inputAccessoryView in ios10. If I remove the inputAccessoryView the error goes away. Very odd

Comment: same issue with me. @any Solution. need help

Comment: The last two lines are a simulator error which occurs when you load a map in your view. It is a known bug for the moment and should be fix when the simulator will be rewritten for iOS 11.

Comment: May be this will be helpful : `https://forums.bignerdranch.com/t/cant-see-any-segmented-control/11165/2`